# Firebase Cloud Functions Unexpected Token On Code Copied From Previous Working Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to preface this by saying I have shown this to some other developers who have no idea what is wrong.

I have a few Cloud functions with Firebase, and all the other ones worked. However, when I try to add another function and simply access the same database using the same code as the other functions I get an "unexpected token ." error. Here is my code:

```
exports.activateLatestDormantGame = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var database = admin.database().ref();
    var gamesDatabase = database.child('games');
    var gameNum;

    var gamesDatabaseQuery = gamesDatabase.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1);
    gamesDatabaseQuery.once('child_added').then((latestGame) => {
        gameNum = parseInt(latestGame.getKey());
        gamesDatabaseQuery.off('child_added');
    }).then(() => {
            gamesDatabase.child(gameNum.toString()).child('isActive').set('true');
        response.end();
    });
});

exports.tallyVotes = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var database = admin.database().ref();

    var gamesDatabaseQuery = database.child('games').orderByKey().limitToFirst(1);

    gamesDatabaseQuery.once('child_added').then((latestGame) => {
        return parseInt(latestGame.getKey());
    }).then((latestGameKey) => {
        var gameDatabaseRef =     database.child('games').child(latestGameKey.toString());
        var numTeams =     gameDatabaseRef.child('teams').child('numTeams').val();
        var votes = [];
        for (team in numTeams) {
            var tallyString = gameDatabaseRef.child('answers').child(team.toString()).val();
            var tallyArray = tallyString.split(',');
            var highestVote = 0;
            for (vote in tallyArray) {
                if (parseInt(vote) > highestVote) {
                    highestVote = parseInt(vote);
                }
            }
            votes.push(highestVote);
        }

        var questionsAskedString = gamesDatabaseRef.child('questionsAsked').val();
        var questionsAskedArray = questionsAskedString.split(',');
        var latestQuestion = questionsAskedArray[questionsAskedArray.length - 1];

        return [latestQuestion, votes, latestGameKey];
    }).then(returnArray) => {
        var answer = database.child('questionDatabase').child(returnArray[0]).child('answerIndex').val();
        var correctTeams = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < returnArray[1].length; i++) {
            if (returnArray[1][i] == answer) {
                correctTeams.push(i);
            }
        }
        database.child('games').child(returnArray[2]).child('correctTeams').set(correctTeams.join(','));
        response.end();
    });
});
```

And here is the error:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

/private/var/folders/zm/qyfsj2ms2yd0w2t748s_v16m0000gn/T/fbfn_8186jLVALtYUfzf1/index.js:48
gamesDatabaseQuery.once('child_added').then((latestGame) => {
                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:18:11
```

I included the activateLatestGame function to show that I am reusing code and it isn't working. I don't even know what the problem here is, any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `(` in this line:

```
}).then(returnArray) => {
```

Should be:

```
}).then((returnArray) => {
```

Comment: Unbelievable... Thank you so much, that turned out to be the issue.